# Which PERSIST should I use in my Java Hibernate application?

Tags: java, hibernate, cascade

I'm using Hibernate in my Java application and when I try to use the `cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST` annotation, there are two PERSIST types in the list. The first is in the `java.persistence` package and the second is in the `java.hibernate` package.

Which should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prefer to use `javax.persistence.` package imports which gives the flexibility to switch across JPA frameworks (Hibernate, jOOQ, etc..).

i.e., If you use `javax.persistence` classes and annotations, then  if you want to migrate to a different JPA provider, in future, because of any reason, you can switch without much (or minimum) development.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using `JPA` with `Hibernate` as your ORM.  `CascadeType.PERSIST` from `JPA`  (`javax.persistence.*`) has exactly the same behaviour as `CascadeType.PERSIST` from `Hibernate`, so choose freely.